# klocwork error - call to function 'GetTokenResponseAsync' may be null and will be dereferenced

Tags: c#, klocwork

I am getting Klocwork error,

> Reference 'this.GetTokenResponseAsync(cancellationToken)' returned from call to function 'GetTokenResponseAsync' at line 101 may be null and will be dereferenced at line 101

and here is code,

```
public async Task<SecurityToken> AcquireTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var tokenResponse = await GetTokenResponseAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return tokenResponse;
    }
```

Is this mean `tokenResponse` can be null? how to fix this?

Comment: It would appear that is the case, yes, but *you* are the one in the best position to figure out whether `GetTokenResponseAsync` can indeed return null, and exactly what "null" comes to mean in your context, and what to do with it.

Comment: I handled those case, but still this Klocwork give me this error, just trying to eliminate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably avoid this error by initialising `tokenResponse` to a value such as `0` on the line above its assignment to `await GetTokenResponseAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)`.

As it's assigned to a value that appears to be on an asynchronous thread it can't be guaranteed that it will ever hold a value.

Comment: @user584018 no problem :)